# HTML page embedded in Flash Movie

Tags: flash

Normally in an HTML page we embed a flash movie now that's a know concept, is it possible to embed an external HTML file into a flash movie?

For eg: If i build a website completely in flash, can i load an external HTML file inside the swf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are using Flex, Yes you could.

http://www.deitte.com/archives/2006/08/finally_updated.htm